# singularity somewhere on the spectral radius circle

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $R({\lambda}) = (\lambda I -A)^{-1}$ be the resolvent operator of a matrix $A$.

Let $A$ be a non-negative matrix.

I have showed that $R({\lambda})$ is analytic except the eigenvalues. But unable to show that it must have at least one singularity somewhere on the spectral radius circle.

Comment: Well, there's only finitely many spectral value, so one of them has to be on the spectral radius circle.

Comment: but what do you mean by singularity of resolvent

Comment: Singularity in the usual sense of analytic function.

Comment: can we claim the singularity is a pole?